# How to design a sample ussd app in java and test using a simulator

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, simulator, ussd

I'm trying to develop a simple hello word application for my assignment in java,
I'm stuck on how to begin, I have downloaded the simulator (Leibcit) but cant figure out how to make it work with my servers,
I'm running Tomcat with Jboss but am open to any other simulators.

Do you perhaps have a detailed description on how I can go about developing an application where a user dials a code, maybe:

*111#

I bring back a menu

1. Hello // user selects 1, it opens another menu 1 how are you 2. Back to previous screen
2. Bye // ends session.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm new here and sorry if this question's been asked, looked around but couldnt find anything i could understand.

Comment: First you have to capture the URL from the USSD Gateway. Then you can use your Browser to simulate needed values to send requests to your server.